# Jwt token always return 401 .net core 3.1 web api

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I'm new at the Jwt. I create new web api running on 3.1 version and my configuration like that ;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            var symmetricKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysupersecretkeytosharewithnooneandalwaysinsideapp"));
            TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = "Management",
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidAudience = "Management",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = symmetricKey,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            };
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            });
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseRouting();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(q => q.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

And my token generator class like that ;

```
        public static string GenerateToken(string jwtKey, string jwtExpireMinutes)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"C280298D-D896-49E2-96AD-5C82243F9048"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,"mfa@gmail.com"),
            };
            var keyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtKey);
            var signInKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByte);
            var expireMinutes = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(jwtExpireMinutes));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(claims: claims, expires: expireMinutes, signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signInKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        }
```

I tried on Postman and I'm getting token successfuly but with this token When I call my method it returns 401 unauthorized.

Controller has these attributes ;

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

These are the results ;

[image: Successfuly token]

[image: 401 Unauthorized]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you check the `aud` (audience) and `iss` (issuer) claim in your jwt token when validating token :

```
ValidIssuer = "Management",
ValidateIssuer = true,
ValidAudience = "Management",
ValidateAudience = true,
```

So that when creating token you should adding these correct claims ,otherwise token validation won't pass :

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(audience: "Management", issuer: "Management", claims: claims, expires: expireMinutes, signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signInKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
```

Comment: yes , thank you!. I spent my two hours to find these mistake :(